# .NET 3.5 SP1 needs "role-management tool" for installation?

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net

I'm currently trying to install .NET 3.5 SP1 on a Windows 2003 SP1 Server and it gives me an error saying that this needs to be done with the "role-management tool".

Where do I find that tool and how to use it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm the role management tool only exists on Windows Server 2008. It's the replacement of Add / Remove Windows Components of the Windows Server 2003.

Is it possible that you need at least SP2 on your windows server 2003?
Or try to install the newest .Net Framework 2.0 Release prior to install the 3.5 release.

Maybe you will find some usefull information in the 3.5 Readme:

[readme](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=40&p=1&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=333325fd-ae52-4e35-b531-508d977d32a6&u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2f9%2fa%2fe%2f9ae0f6cc-7032-408e-9ca7-989f9e4af4ec%2fdotNetReadMe.htm)

Comment: Well, okay I tried 2.0 before and now it gives an error about fusioning that's not working...

Comment: hi 

can you post the whole error message? does the application or system eventlog log anything

Answer (score 0):

Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: mmc.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 6.0.6001.18000
  Problem Signature 03: 47918d09
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager
  Problem Signature 05: 6.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4791a748
  Problem Signature 07: 1909
  Problem Signature 08: d
  Problem Signature 09: System.BadImageFormatException
  OS Version:   6.0.6001.2.1.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    2057

Read our privacy statement:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409